# Changing all instances of across the firebase database or best practices for multiple listeners to a single node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an example firebase database structure like this,

```
{
  "posts": {
 "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
  "uid": "0OBRNR61rDagBx6cXmLqVGkBpTZ4",
  "photoURL": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "message": "Hello my name is John Smith"
},
"-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
   "uid": "13qChHOh4eWu0wb8Bb54P3DlnTU5",
  "photoURL": "YYYYYYYYYY",
  "displayName": "Jenny Johnson",
  "message": "Hello my name is Jenny Johnson"
},
"-JRGUKnCuPTFYknj0opx": {
  "uid": "13qChHOh4eWu0wb8Bb54P3DlnTU5",
  "photoURL": "YYYYYYYYYY",
  "displayName": "Jenny Johnson",
  "message": "Hey Whats Up"
},
"-JROHHaIs-jNTOZOCjtZ": {
  "uid": "0OBRNR61rDagBx6cXmLqVGkBpTZ4",
  "photoURL": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "message": "Doing well thanks"
 },
},
 "Users": {
"0OBRNR61rDagBx6cXmLqVGkBpTZ4":{
    "displayName": "John Smith",
    "photoURL": "XXXXXXXXXXX" 
},
"13qChHOh4eWu0wb8Bb54P3DlnTU5":{
    "displayName": "Jenny Johnson",
    "photoURL": "YYYYYYYYYY" 
 }
}
```

If I changed the displayName of "John Smith" or the "photoURL", what is the best way to change those attributes across all the posts where those would align? (i.e. all posts that were originally by John Smith based on the uid, would be changed to ... say Bob Smith if I changed the displayName of users/0OBRNR61rDagBx6cXmLqVGkBpTZ4 to Bob Smith )

Or, would the best way be to include a ref on each of the posts to their uid's displayName and photoURL?